# Vuetify icons not showing up (only see a square)

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

When I try to use a v-icon, I am not able to see the icon but just a square as shown in the image attached. all the other vuetify components work fine.

I am using it just like this `<v-icon> mdi-domain </v-icon>`

I have tried `import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";` in main.js but it has not worked. I dont want to use the CDN link.

It is also not showing up in the expandable vuetify table. [image]

Comment: Is there an error in the console? Are you using `css-loader` in your webpack.config.js?

Comment: nope. no errors in the console and I am using css-loader in the webpack.config file. I am also handling all the fonts and scss files present in the folder.